# problem in bootstrap 5 theming in rtl version

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, bootstrap-5

i don't know should i place bootstrap.rtl.min.css before or after app.scss theming in reactjs

[image]

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";

$font-sizes: (
  1: 12px,
  2: 14px,
  3: 16px,
  4: 18px,
  5: 20px,
  6: 22px,
  7: 24px,
  8: 26,
);

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "font-size":
      map-merge(
        map-get($utilities, "font-size"),
        (
          values: $font-sizes,
        )
      ),
    "rounded": (
      property: border-radius,
      class: rounded,
      values: (
        null: 4px,
        0: 0,
        "sm": 3px,
        "md": 8px,
        circle: 50%,
      ),
    ),
  )
);

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

placing it after app.scss rtl override and in before ltr version override because it's called in app.scss